# I could not install educational desktop on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and cannot find it in software centre

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-center, edubuntu

I have a problem with finding play on linux, movie player as in 12.04 in 16.04 LTS version. I can't find educational desktop or edubuntu and these important softwares in new ubuntu software centre of ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `apt-cache policy edubuntu-desktop`?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install playonlinux gnome-mplayer edubuntu-desktop edubuntu-artwork edubuntu-docs edubuntu-fonts edubuntu-menueditor
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install edubuntu-desktop`

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You won't find the Edubuntu packages unless you [enable the Universe Repository.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) Once you have done so you should be able to find the majority of the [Edubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=edubuntu&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) for your release (16.04 Xenial in this case) in the Software Center. Edubuntu Desktop is a Meta package that should include the majority of what you need. There's a list of recommended optional additions [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/edubuntu-desktop)

Sources:

https://askubuntu.com/a/888602/225694

[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=edubuntu&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/edubuntu-desktop